# Create fixed header using html and css

Tags: html, css

This is the html for the header-bar:

```
<div class="header-container">
  <img class="logo" src="/images/logo.png" width="102" height="31" alt="Logo" />
  <input type="text" id="header-search-input" placeholder="Search" />
  <div class="right-container">
    <a href="/logout/" class="right">Logout</a>
    <a href="/" class="right">Home</a> 
  </div><!-- .right-container ends -->
</div><!-- .header-container ends -->
```

And this is the css:

```
  .header-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2000;
    height: 57px;
}

.right-container {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 200px;
    position: fixed;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #516475;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 19px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 19px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.right:hover {
    float: right;
    border-bottom-width: thick;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #21964F;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #21A559;
}

.logo{
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

#header-search-input{
    color: #424A61;
    border: thin solid #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 26px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ninjaagnes/4KMDf/)

The  tags move out of it whe a window is made smaller. I want them inside the header fixed.

Comment: what is the issue? your header is fixed in your fiddle...

Comment: also add  `left:0;right:0;` to the class `header-container`

Comment: the <a> tags move out of it whe a window is made smaller. I want them inside the geader fixed.

Comment: remove margin-right:200px:from rightcontainer class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the other elements are going to get in the way but all you said was the `<a>`s.  Here's the fix:

### CSS:

```
.right-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 5%;
}
```

### [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nt9W4/)

Let me know if there are more specific customisations you were looking for so I can help you achieve your end-goal.

And obviously the numbers are adjustable based on your needs (`right: 10%;` / `right: 20%;` / etc)

Comment: this fixed the <a> tags :D but, now i need to fix the logo and the search input. Please help.

Comment: You can change the padding to be percentages and align the logo and search to the left and give them percentage `width`s as well.  This will make them shrink as the window shrinks.  The percentage on the `padding` will have the same effect

Comment: You'll have to compromise at some point and either remove one or more of the elements or resize the whole navbar and elements inside.  It seems to me you want a responsive design.  If this is the case, this site is a very good way to learn:  http://www.alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design - and of course any branching links in the article are crucial as well so do click them (fluid grids, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try this link: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zS7Ny/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <table class="head">
        <tr>
            <td>Head 1</td>
            <td>Head 1</td>
            <td>Head 1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="inner_table">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    width: 352px;
}

.wrap table {
    width: 300px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table tr td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

table.head tr td {
    background: #eee;
}

.inner_table {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible without using <table>. Anyways, it is isn't working.

Comment: but this didn't work for me. This isn't what I needed.